# Why does a non-gaussian distribution imply noise in LIGO?

Tags: general-relativity, error-analysis, noise, ligo

So I'm trying to understand why do we expect a [non-gaussian distribution to imply correlation in LIGO](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.04169)? Like how do we know the default noise distribution is gaussian? I am concerned about coordinate transformations. More specifically different observes will not measure the same gaussian.

Answer (score 0):

A statistician to whom I posed a question almost identical to this one gave me a very wise answer, as follows:

It is natural to expect that a process subject to small, random perturbations will furnish a gaussian distribution (now wave your hands vigorously in the air and mumble, "central limit theorem"). You can call those perturbations "noise" if you want.

A non-gaussian distribution indicates that the outcome you expected to be gaussian has in fact been subject to some sort of *selection* or *filtering* or *processing* (which process she described as "the hand of a human") which removes or alters the noise- yielding a distribution containing "funny business" (this is a highly technical term used only by really cool and hip statisticians).

In this sense, the presence of funny business in the distribution indicates the hand of a human in a broad sense. In the LIGO case the signal processing involves correlating two signals with one another.

Comment: Why doesn't this argument work for the juttner distribution? I mean that's not a Gaussian

Comment: Although it's not fully true. There can be long-range interactions also in the measured system (whatever caused the signal), even in case of random perturbations. In such case there would be a q-Gaussian or q-Levy distribution (Tsallis and Gell man worked out the q-central limit theorem), taking into account such processes). It is not precise to assume Gaussian random fluctuations, although typically it is a very good hint/choice)

Comment: I would only add that *linear* filtering does not change the distribution from Gaussian process to a non-Gaussian one. To make the change you need a nonlinear transformation (filter). A correlator is a non-linear transformation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the link between non-Gaussian random processes and "the hand of a human." In fact I would say that truly Gaussian processes are so rare in Nature that to see a truly Gaussian process would make me wonder if I was looking at idealized, simulated data. Some examples of natural processes that will generate random, non-Gaussian outcomes would be an anharmonic quantum oscillator, transient rumbling in the Earth in seismometer data (which can appear in LIGO data), and [thirsty ravens](https://alog.ligo-wa.caltech.edu/aLOG/index.php?callRep=37630).

Comment: @andrew, in my former lifetime as an engineer I used sets of measurements consisting of over a million data points each to build distributions and they were textbook examples of gaussian distributions. Not only that but when humans intervened to sort out the 3-sigma "out of spec" parts before loading the data into the database, the truncation was glaringly obvious.